# CSS Selector Code Assistance For Data Scraping

Tags: css

It's near the bottom, the only "2.5". Closest I could get was "tbody:nth-child(2) > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(2)", but that doesn't work. I cannot figure it out, trying to scrape data from page to create energy sensor within Home Assistant. I don't really know anything about CSS stuff, but would like to get this working, especially with as close as I gotten to it. Thanks.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <link href="css/log.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <title></title>
  <style type="text/css">
    body {
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
    }
    
    #upheader {
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 20;
      visibility: hidden;
    }
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    i = 0;

    function getWidth(src) {
      if (document.defaultView && document.defaultView.getComputedStyle) {
        return parseInt(document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(src, null).getPropertyValue("width"));
      } else if (src.clientWidth) {
        return src.clientWidth;
      }
      return null;
    }

    function setWidth(target, src) {
      if (target == null || src == null || src.nodeType != 1) {
        return;
      }
      target.width = getWidth(src);
      for (var i = target.childNodes.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        setWidth(target.childNodes[i], src.childNodes[i]);
      }
    }

    function HeaderAndCover(func) {
      var header = document.getElementById("upheader");
      var cover = document.getElementById("upset");
      if (header && cover) {
        func(header, cover);
      }
    }

    function fixHeaders() {
      HeaderAndCover(function(header, cover) {
        if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop) {
          header.style.top = document.documentElement.scrollTop + "px";
        } else if (document.body) {
          header.style.top = document.body.scrollTop + "px";
        }
      });
    }

    function setHeaders() {
      HeaderAndCover(function(header, cover) {
        header.width = getWidth(cover);
        setWidth(header.getElementsByTagName("thead")[0], cover.getElementsByTagName("thead")[0]);
        header.style.visibility = "visible";
      });
    }
    var setUntilLoadIntervalID = null;

    function runload() {
      if (setUntilLoadIntervalID) {
        clearInterval(setUntilLoadIntervalID);
        setHeaders();
      }
    }
    if (document.getElementById && document.getElementsByTagName) {
      window.onscroll = function() {
        fixHeaders();
      };
      window.onresize = function() {
        setHeaders();
        fixHeaders();
      };
      setUntilLoadIntervalID = setInterval("setHeaders()", 1000);
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body onload="runload()">
  <table id="upheader" cellpadding="2" border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="1" class="logTable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th width="180px">Time</th>
        <th width="170px">Interval Energy(kWh)</th>
        <th width="170px">Interval Cost(units)</th>
        <th width="150px">Interval CO2(kg)</th>
        <th width="150px">Energy (kWh)</th>
        <th width="120px">Cost (units)</th>
        <th width="120px">CO2 (kg)</th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
  <table id="upset" cellpadding="2" border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="1" class="logTable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th width="180px">Time</th>
        <th width="170px">Interval Energy(kWh)</th>
        <th width="170px">Interval Cost(units)</th>
        <th width="150px">Interval CO2(kg)</th>
        <th width="150px">Energy (kWh)</th>
        <th width="120px">Cost (units)</th>
        <th width="120px">CO2 (kg)</th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>01/16/2022 00:00:00
          <td>2.5
            <td>0.30
              <td>1.500
                <td>1521.8
                  <td>182.62
                    <td>913.080
                      <td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>01/15/2022 00:00:00
          <td>2.6
            <td>0.31
              <td>1.560
                <td>1519.3
                  <td>182.32
                    <td>911.580
                      <td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <tbody>
  </table>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting tbody:nth-child(2) but there are no tbody elements that are anything but the first child (of their table parent).

You are trying to select the second table, the first row in that table and the second cell in that row so you can use:

```
table:nth-child(2)>tbody>tr:nth-child(1)>td:nth-child(2)
```

(but be aware that if you have a more complex structure, with tables within tables, you may need to be even more explicit about the table you want to select, perhaps in relation to their level within body).

```css
table:nth-child(2)>tbody>tr:nth-child(1)>td:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<table id="upheader" cellpadding="2" border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="1" class="logTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th width="180px">Time</th>
      <th width="170px">Interval Energy(kWh)</th>
      <th width="170px">Interval Cost(units)</th>
      <th width="150px">Interval CO2(kg)</th>
      <th width="150px">Energy (kWh)</th>
      <th width="120px">Cost (units)</th>
      <th width="120px">CO2 (kg)</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
<table id="upset" cellpadding="2" border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="1" class="logTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th width="180px">Time</th>
      <th width="170px">Interval Energy(kWh)</th>
      <th width="170px">Interval Cost(units)</th>
      <th width="150px">Interval CO2(kg)</th>
      <th width="150px">Energy (kWh)</th>
      <th width="120px">Cost (units)</th>
      <th width="120px">CO2 (kg)</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>01/16/2022 00:00:00
        <td>2.5
          <td>0.30
            <td>1.500
              <td>1521.8
                <td>182.62
                  <td>913.080
                    <td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>01/15/2022 00:00:00
        <td>2.6
          <td>0.31
            <td>1.560
              <td>1519.3
                <td>182.32
                  <td>911.580
                    <td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <tbody>
</table>
```